# Given a set of points, build a quad mesh such that each point is in the center of a quad

Tags: mesh

I have a complex grid of points in sort of an elliptical orientation.  I would like to make a 2D quad mesh such that each point is in the center of a quad.

I had been trying to accomplish this programmatically with some difficulty, then I though maybe this functionality is already implemented in Blender.

Is there some way that I can generate such a mesh given such a set of points with Blender?

**EDIT**

Here are a few images to better show what I am trying to do.  The given points are in blue.  I want to surround each point with a quad and have minimal gaps between them.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Dupli verts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/index.html?#instancing)

- 1st mesh with center vertices, under *Properties > Object > Duplication* switch Verts:

  [image]
- 2nd mesh a simple quad (add plane) and parent it under 1st mesh:

  [image]
- if you want to convert it to editable mesh, do it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Edit: To rotate them like in your picture, connect your points with edges so they form concentric ellipses. Extrude them so you have some polygons - this will give those verts proper normals:

[image]

Check the *rotation* in that *Duplication* tab and convert to geometry, delete the original plane, concentric ellipses and delete the bottom dupli-objects:

[image]

The spacing is determined by the position of your input vertices so this should end up in what you want..

Comment: But then how do transform the quads so that they are connected seamlessly?

Comment: @MVTC Well how do you want them to connect? Can you post example finished part of the mesh? Hand-drawn maybe? If the mesh will be too specific you would probably need to generate it with python.

Comment: Maybe what I want can't be done that easily.  Right now, I am generated the images I've shown.  But you can see that some gaps are larger than others.  I am defining the quads by 4 polar coordinates.  If I increase r or theta for all of them, then some will overlap.  Imagine that each quad had some internal force, trying to expand itself, and when two edges meet, the push against each-other and deform each-other a little as to be in full solid contact.

Comment: @MVTC So you want non-orthogonal quads? Some Voronoi type of thing? That changes all, I had a wrong impression. I'll try to think of something, fracturize a plane with particles in your center points - the center points will need to be at very specific positions for the voronoi cells to have 4 sides..